# How would I set the label of my UserControl at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's the setup: I've created a user control MyUserControl. On this control is a simple label. When I drop a new instance of this control on a form, I would like the label to be the name of the control. For example, if this is the first instance of the control, VStudio automatically sets the name of it to be "myUserControl1". I would simply like the label to read "myUserControl1". If this is the fifth control, VStudio will name it myUserControl5. I would like the label to change accordingly... but only if it hasn't already been set. Once I set it to read "The Label", it should be left alone.

I thought it would be easy. In the constructor, set label1.Text = this.Name. But then I realized, at instantiation this.Name is simply MyUserControl. It hasn't been named yet by VisualStudio and the CONTAINING InitializeComponent() method.

Ah! I'll just override the "Name" field. When it gets set, check for DesignMode and update the label!... but I can't override the name. It's not virtual or abstract. I can use "new" to force it, but then, it never fires, thus defeating the purpose.

Which event can I use to denote when the designer has named the control? I know that the redmond folks do it all the time when they drop a control on the form, so it's very possible. I'm actually quite stumped by this little riddle.

Comment: Interesting challenge. I only came up with a few ways that work fine until you delete or cut/paste any of the user controls. The Name property just doesn't seem to be actually changed at design time. Gotta do some real work now... good luck!

Comment: This requires a custom designer.  ControlDesigner.InitializeNewComponent() is a good example.  Problem is, the designer for UserControl is not public so can't be derived from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's the final answer:

Per Hans' suggestion, it did require a ControlDesigner. I created a simple designer that would interface with some internal properties, and I did get it to work. Here's the catch, though: It's a bit of a hack. There doesn't seem to be a single field that has the value I'm looking for, so I had to do a `.ToString()` on an object, then parse out the first section. I figured that's about as clean as it is going to get.

```
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public MyControlDesigner()
    {
    }


    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);

        MyControl control1 = this.Component as MyControl;
        control1.LabelText = control1.ToString().Split(" ".ToCharArray())[0];
    }
}
```

Then at the top of MyControl, I simply added a new attribute:

```
[DesignerAttribute(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    ...

    // Using the property "Text" Causes Visual Studio to crash!!!
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set { label1.Text = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, it wasn't very complicated, but it is a bit hack-ish. The control locked up the IDE when I tried to override "Text". Not sure why, but when I called it "LabelText", it worked perfectly.

Comment: UserControl already has a Text property, so you have to change it to "public new string Text {..." in order to use it.

Answer (score 2):

What about overriding the [OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.onload.aspx) method, which calls the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load.aspx) event?

If that doesn't work, it's a bit sloppy, but you could use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event, or the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) event as these are both called after the `Name` property is set by the designer (it sets the values in alphabetical order).

Comment: It still left the name as "MyUserControl" instead of myUserControl5.

Comment: Both of them? Hmmm... my only other suggestion would be setting a timer to wait keep checking for a change (then stopping it when there is a change).

Comment: No. I'm certain that the TextChanged or SizeChanged event would work, but -- as you noted -- it's very sloppy. I know there's got to be a very simple method to do this. Introducing sloppy code for such a simple thing is bound to lead to other errors down the road.

Comment: This is very true and I'd be searching for another way if I were in your shoes. But if it came to it and I couldn't find a better way, I'd implement that and heavily comment it explaining what it does for future reference..

Comment: Maybe you should re-think the reasoning? Perhaps the Name isn't the right thing for the job. Usually the designer sets the Text property of a `UserControl` to this name, could you just use that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the designer file.  For example, say I have a Form named Form1.  So, I would have Form1.cs, Form1.resx, and Form1.Designer.cs in visual studio.  If opening Form1.Designer.cs you will see this:

```
   #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
```

This is a warning, but you can still edit this file.

Here's a sample edit, I am setting label3 text to label1's name:

```
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(371, 146);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 10;
            this.label3.Text = "label3";
            //My Edit
            this.label3.Text = this.label1.Name;
```

Now in the form designer in Visual Studio I see that label3 has label1's name:

[image]

A similiar approach could be used for your user control.

Comment: The designer can regenerate this code at any time and will put it back to a constant string whenever it is refreshed. Plus, at this time you cannot garentee that `label1.Name` has been set.

Comment: Good point, definately would have to make a comment or alert everyone of this because the change could be blown away inadvertantly.  Any code that is autogened has this issue, thus the warning at the top of the code file.  As long as the custom code is after label1.name has been set, it's OK. Looking at the designer code would be necessary to ensure the cutom code is in the right place.  Not saying this is the best, but could be a viable workaround.  I don't think there is direct access to the auto generated designer file other than editing the template.

Comment: Indeed. No solution is perfect though. Usually if there isn't an easy way of doing it, it means Microsoft don't want you to do it. I can't see their reasoning for this one though.