# C# Set Default text for a custom TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to create a custom TextBox that when Drag & Dropped into the form shows "customTextBox1", "customTextBox2" just like happens in labels and buttons.

I tried to do this:

```
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ReadOnly = true;
        TabStop = false;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        Text = "customTextBox";
    }
```

The other properties work fine but to show the text i need to build or start the program after dragging the customTextBox or the text will remain empty and the number of the customTextBox doesn't go up after dragging more CustomTextBox.

Note: I don't want any PlaceHolder or similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a partial duplicate of this thread [How would I set the label of my UserControl at design time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052635/how-would-i-set-the-label-of-my-usercontrol-at-design-time), but the answer there is not exactly applicable because you're inheriting from `TextBox` and not `UserControl` and the initialization routine is a little different. It's not intuitive at all to do what you're asking, which is unfortunate since all of the default text controls set their `Text` property to their `Name` property when they're initially created by the designer.

The trick is implementing a `ControlDesigner` (from `System.Windows.Forms.Design`) just for your component. `ControlDesigner.InitializeNewComponent` is called once by the WinForms designer, whenever a new control is created on the form. That's your opportunity to set the `Text` property to the `Name` property without having side effects with your non-design code, and without interfering with the designer's serialization of your component.

I verified this works in the designer - it properly sets the `Text` field to match the designer's generated `Name` field, but once the control is created by the designer, the `Text` and `Name` fields remain separately editable, just like in a default `TextBox` or `Label` control.

**To make this work, you must add a project reference to `System.Design`**, which is what contains the `System.Windows.Forms.Design` namespace.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace StackOverflowAnswers.CustomControlDefaultText
{
    class CustomTextBoxDesigner : ControlDesigner
    {
        public CustomTextBoxDesigner()
        {

        }

        public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
        {
            // Allow the base implementation to set default values,
            // which are provided by the designer.
            base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);

            // Now that all the basic properties are set, we
            // do our one little step here. Component is a
            // property exposed by ControlDesigner and refers to
            // the current IComponent being designed.
            CustomTextBox myTextBox = Component as CustomTextBox;
            if(myTextBox != null)
            {
                myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    // This attribute sets the designer for your derived version of TextBox
    [Designer(typeof(CustomTextBoxDesigner))]
    class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public CustomTextBox() : base()
        {
            ReadOnly = true;
            TabStop = false;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting three errors
1) ControlDesigner could not be found
2) 'CustomTextBoxDesigner.InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary)': no suitable method found to override
3) Component is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Did you include all the `using` statements at the top of the code sample I provided?

Comment: Yes, the using System.Windows.Forms.Design; seems useless though, it becomes gray on visual studio

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? I was using .NET 4.5.2 in my test project, and I copy and pasted the entire CustomTextBox.cs file into the code sample here. All you should need to change is the `namespace StackOverflowAnswers.CustomControlDefaultText` line to your own namespace and it should work.

Comment: Just realized what I forgot. You need to add a project reference to `System.Design` to make this work. My mistake for leaving that out. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the confusion on my side. Good luck with your project!